# Volume of a solid bounded by surfaces

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, multivariable-calculus, volume

can someone help me with setting up the required integral?

The solid is bounded by $z = 4x^2 + 4y^2 -27$ and by $z = x^2+y^2$. Should I project this on $x-y$ plane or use cylindrical or spherical coordinates or do something else? I am a bit lost and could use an example to crystalize how to approach these types of problems.

Comment: Cylindrical coordinates are the best. However, the two are cylinders with common axis. Therefore, the "solid" is infinite.

Comment: This should be one simple problem regarding triple integrals. Next, you should be able to figure what is the projection on desired coordinate plane. Then you will proceed with calculation in cylindrical coordinates... Can you follow my hints?

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak Yes, these types of hints are basically useless. Can you suggest how to project on the desired coordinate plane?

Comment: In your problem solid is bounded by 2 surfaces. First action that should comes to mind is to find intersection between them, i.e. to check is there a solution for $z \text{ (1st surface) }=z \text{ (2nd surface)}$. In your problem we have to check what is $4x^2 + 4y^2 - 27 = x^2 + y^2$. I believe you can figure that now, and proceed.... Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I get $3x^2 + 3y^2 - 27 =0$, from this I get $3x^2 + 3y^2 <= 27$. What should I do with this further? I get from this that $\rho = \sqrt{\frac{27}{3}}$. How do I calculate the angle?

Comment: Since you get $\rho \le 3$ it represent a central circle with radius $3$. Hence for cylindrical coordinate $\varphi$ we have $\varphi \in [0, 2\pi]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using cylindrical coordinates, you have

$ \rho^2 = x^2 + y^2 $

So the two paraboloids are $ z = 4 \rho^2 - 27 $ and $ z = \rho^2 $

These are equal when $ 3 \rho^2 = 27 $, i.e. $\rho = 3 $

Now the volume integral is

$ V = \displaystyle \int_{\phi = 0}^{2 \pi} \int_{\rho = 0 }^{\rho = 3 } \int_{z = 4 \rho^2 - 27} ^ { \rho^2 } d z \ \rho \ d \rho \ d \phi $

This simplifies to

$ V = 2 \pi \displaystyle \int_{\rho = 0 }^{\rho = 3 } \rho(27 - 3 \rho^2) d \rho $

And finally,

$ V = 2 \pi \left( \dfrac{243}{2} - \dfrac{243}{4} \right) = \dfrac{243 \pi}{2} $